# How to make matched items bold with jQuery AJAX filtering

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am learning jQuery and i am doing practice on filtering.
I have this snippet for filtering lists with input. This code removes the items from the list if they don't match the input. But I just want the matching items to be **bold** and keep the non-matching items same as before.
How can I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#myList li a").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

The LI gets a bold class

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("input", function() {
    const value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList li")          // I assum you want to bold on the LI
      .removeClass("bold")
      .find("a")
      .filter(function() {
        return value && $(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(value)
      }).each(function() {
        $(this).closest("li").addClass("bold")
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.bold a {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="myInput" autocomplete="off" />
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a href="">Mice are fun</a></li>
  <li><a href="">So are turtles</a></li>
</ul>
```

The A gets the bold class - no filter needed

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("input", function() {
    const value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList li a").each(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("bold", value && $(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(value))
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.bold {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="myInput" autocomplete="off" />
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a href="">Mice are fun</a></li>
  <li><a href="">So are turtles</a></li>
</ul>
```